# Javascript - Firebase Child key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with Firebase.

I would like to display the key of a given.
How can I do ?

```
const database = firebase.database();
const login = firebase.auth();      
database.ref('peso/' + user.uid + '/' + anno).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

[image: key]

I would like to memorize the 4 in one variable and the other given in another.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows:

```
const database = firebase.database();
const login = firebase.auth();      
database.ref('peso/' + user.uid + '/' + anno).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

You will find the doc for DataSnapshot here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key

Answer (score 0):

does not work.
I am attaching the screenshot of the database and also the one that prints me.
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvxtO.jpg)

[Console Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPPSE.jpg)